# Try to print strings in assembler

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I am trying to print a few string in MIPS, but when i try print the first message, program prints all of them.

```
.data
first_msg: .ascii "Podaj pierwsza liczbe: "
second_msg: .ascii "Podaj druga liczbe: "
third_msg: .ascii "Wieksza z tych liczb jest liczba "

.text
main:
la $a0, first_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Sorry for my bad language and thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please show the output and the system details

Comment: It's output: "Podaj pierwsza liczbe: Podaj druga liczbe: Wieksza z tych liczb jest liczba 
-- program is finished running --" I have a win xp and i use MARS 4.3 to run .asm file.

Answer (score 2):

You do not null-terminate the strings. Use `asciiz` instead of `ascii`.

```
.ascii str
Store the string in memory, but do not null-terminate it.

.asciiz str
Store the string in memory and null-terminate it.
```

Read [this](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node7.html).

So, your code becomes:

```
.data
first_msg: .asciiz "Podaj pierwsza liczbe: "
second_msg: .asciiz "Podaj druga liczbe: "
third_msg: .asciiz "Wieksza z tych liczb jest liczba "

.text
main:
la $a0, first_msg
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```